# Resolving IServiceBus using IoC

Tags: castle-windsor, masstransit, topshelf

I am using MassTransit for message queuing (using RabbitMQ), Castle Windsor as my IoC and Topshelf to run my app as a windows service.

But I run to this problem which is so weird to me.

This is my code

I have a service

```
public class TestService : IService
{

    public void Start() {}
    public void Stop() {}

}
```

and here is my main code (where is setup Topshelf)

```
public class Program
{

   public static IWindsorContainer;

   public static void Main()
   {
            Container = new WindsorContainer();
            Container.Register(

                Component.For<IServiceBus>().Named("serviceBus").UsingFactoryMethod(CreateServiceBus()).LifeStyle.Singleton,

                Component.For<IService>().ImplementedBy<SmppListenerService>().Named("test").LifeStyle.Singleton

            );

        Logger.Trace("Before Resolving");
        var bus = Container.Resolve<IServiceBus>("serviceBus");
        var service = Container.Resolve<IService>("test");
        Logger.Trace("After Resolving");

        HostFactory.Run(x =>
        {
            x.Service<IService>(config =>
            {
                config.ConstructUsing(o => service);
                config.WhenStarted(o => { o.Start();  });
                config.WhenStopped(o => { Container.Dispose(); } );
            });

            x.RunAsLocalSystem();
            x.SetServiceName("test");
            x.SetDescription("test d");
            x.SetDisplayName("test dn");

        });


   }

}
```

This code works just find when debugging but when I run it as a service it stops at resolving service bus with no exceptions until windows says it didn't respond to control function. Note that it works on the first time, doesn't work on second time, works on third and so forth.

I don't understand why but when I create IServiceBus outside of IoC it works pretty find.

Thanks

Peyman

Comment: What's the `CreateServiceBus` look like? If you can't create the bus then it's likely there's an issue with permissions or connections. A common problem with service/debug is permissions for logs or MSMQ (I know MSMQ permissions don't apply for you though).

Comment: Try running as a process, but without the debugger.
Try to run as a service using your account instead of LocalSystem.

Comment: Did you ever get anywhere with this? If not, I'd reach out to the mailing list and see if you can't get more help.

Answer (score 1):

Container setup must be done inside Topshelf configuration, in the ConstructUsing() method of service. Try that your Service class holds the container.